# What's a functor on the category of monads?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, category-theory

> Note, this question is not about "monoids in the category of endofunctors".  Nor is it directly about `Functor`s (a `Monad` is always a `Functor`, but this question is concerned mainly about monad transformers)

---

The [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Select.html#t:SelectT) on Haskell's `SelectT` monad transformer states that

> `SelectT` is not a functor on the category of monads, and many operations cannot be lifted through it.

1. What's the *category of monads*?  What are the arrows in that category?
2. Why are some monad transformers functors on the category of monads (`MaybeT`, `RWST`, etc), but some not (`ContT`, `SelectT`)?
3. What good does it do, from a programming perspective, to be a functor on the category of monads?  Why should I care as a consumer of the library?

Comment: I am not versed in category theory, but perhaps it means that SelectT monads aren't just "wrappers" for their base monad? It's easy to convert a `IO String` into a `MaybeT IO String`, but it's not possible to convert an `IO String` into a `SelectT <whatever type> IO String`

Comment: Since a monad is a functor, the arrows would be natural transformations.

Comment: For some of those subquestions, you might find it useful to have a look at [the `Control.Monad.Morph` docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph-1.1.3/docs/Control-Monad-Morph.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. What's the *category of monads*? What are the arrows in that category?

The category where the objects are monads, i.e., types `T` of kind `Type -> Type` with `Monad` instances, and the arrows `A -> B` are *natural transformations* between their underlying functors, conventionally represented in Haskell by functions of type `forall x. A x -> B x` (although strictly speaking parametricity is a stronger condition than naturality).

There’s an implementation of this in the [mmorph](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmorph) package.

The initial object in this category is `Identity`, since for any monad `T` there’s exactly one natural transformation `forall x. Identity x -> T x`. Dually, I think the final object is `Const ()`.

> 2. Why are some monad transformers functors on the category of monads (`MaybeT`, `RWST`, etc), but some not (`ContT`, `SelectT`)?

A functor in this category would need a lifted `fmap`:

```
fmap'
  :: forall m n. (Monad m, Monad n)
  => (forall x. m x -> n x) -> forall x. T m x -> T n x
```

And you can’t implement this in general for `ContT` and `SelectT`. I’m not sure precisely why, but it seems to depend on variance: we’re trying to implement a *covariant* functor, but `ContT` and `SelectT` are *invariant* in their underlying monads, e.g., `m` occurs both positively and negatively in the `(a -> m r) -> m r` inside a `ContT r m a`.

> 3. What good does it do, from a programming perspective, to be a functor on the category of monads? Why should I care as a consumer of the library?

If you have a general way to “run” a monad `m` in a monad `n`, you can’t necessarily lift that into `ContT` or `SelectT`; you’re stuck with the more restricted mapping operations like these:

```
mapSelectT :: (m a -> m a) -> SelectT r m a -> SelectT r m a
mapContT   :: (m r -> m r) -> ContT   r m a -> ContT   r m a
```

Where the underlying monad and result type are fixed. So you can’t always freely hoist actions within a stack that uses these transformers.

Comment: So it's actually just the functor category, restricted to those functors that are monads? I suspected this, but wasn't sure.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: That seems to be the way folks generally use the term, yeah. I could certainly imagine more exotic things by that name.

Comment: If a monad transformer is not functorial then the monad cannot be used at an arbitrary place in the monad stack because you can't lift its operations into the stack. You are then restricted to putting that monad at the deep end of the stack. Witness how all monad stacks involving `IO` always put `IO` at the deep end of the stack; this is because `IO` doesn't actually have a transformer. The same restriction applies to `Cont`, `Select`, and the codensity monads, because their transformers don't have `hoist` and are not functorial.